# Custom Widget for GetX Dialog?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am currently new in GetX.
I know about showDialog() method from Flutter. But, what I want to achieve is a custom dialog derived from Get.defaultDialog() using the template image attached below. In this [documentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-creating-dialog-in-using-getx-library/) link, I know that there is a variable named: "content", which we can replace with a widget within Get.defaultDialog().

Does anyone know what does it mean? Does using this "content" can replace the entire widget of Get.defaultDialog() template layout, or is there something I have to done to achieve it? Any tips and tricks are welcome. Thank you.

[image: Example of dialog]

Comment: Why don't you try it out instead of asking?

Comment: @dabbel - Actually my main task is to develop backend, and I just need help to reduce my burden as I have to do front-end too. If anyone can help me out, then it would be great to save time. Besides, this use case doesn't exist yet in stackoverflow. If it really does, I won't ask for question here.

Comment: Never mind. I'll do it all step by step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Get.dialog()` instead of `Get.defaultDialog()`.
Or pass any `Widget` to the `content` named parameter of `Get.defaultDialog()`

Answer (score 7):

```dart
  Get.dialog(
            barrierDismissible: false,
            Dialog(
              backgroundColor: AppColor.transparent,
              child: WillPopScope(
                onWillPop: () async => false,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: Text("No Internet Connection"),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height:10,),
                      Image.asset(AppImage.internetConnection,height:30),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Text("Please check your connection again,or connect to wi-fi.",),
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        color: AppColor.grey,
                        thickness: 1,
                      ),
                      Inkwell(
                        onTap: () {
                            Get.to(() => const AllVideoScreen());
                        }, child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          height:50,
                          width: 30,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: AppColor.blackWhite,
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                             "Refresh",
                            
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on my understanding, the best option for your use case would be to use `Get.dialog()`. This is because `Get.defaultDialog()` retains space for the `title` even if it's set to an empty string. The `content` property will only replace the `middleText` area with the widget that's assigned to it.

Here's an example of using `Get.dialog()`:

```
Get.dialog(
  Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Material(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  const Text(
                    "Title Text",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 15),
                  const Text(
                    "Message Text",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  //Buttons
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          child: const Text(
                            'NO',
                          ),
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            minimumSize: const Size(0, 45),
                            primary: Colors.amber,
                            onPrimary: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          child: const Text(
                            'YES',
                          ),
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            minimumSize: const Size(0, 45),
                            primary: Colors.amber,
                            onPrimary: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```